# get only city names in the Google Directions API

Tags: google-api, google-directions-api

I am using the Google direction API to get itineraries based on points that can be **cities** only (not addresses, countries, or any POI).

I would like to parse the city name out of the response, but the API return a somewhat cumbersome string that includes postcodes, states, countries, etc. Nevertheless, it appears that this format is not always the same, which makes it somewhat dangerous to try to get a sub-string out it. Example:

**[link 1](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Sydney%2C+New+South+Wales%2C+Australia&destination=Bendigo%2C+Victoria%2C+Australia&waypoints=Albury%2C+New+South+Wales%2C+Australia&avoid=&departure_time=1411817575&sensor=false&optimize=true)** *This call returns Australian locations names with postcodes, states, and country.*

```
"start_address": "Albury NSW 2640, Australia",
"end_address": "Bendigo VIC 3550, Australia",
```

**[link 2](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Paris&destination=Metz&waypoints=Reims&avoid=&departure_time=1411817575&sensor=false&optimize=true)** *this call returns French locations that have no region nor postcode.*

```
start_address": "Reims, France",
end_address": "Metz, France",
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note: here is the temporary solution that relies on parsing the string : `$end_address = $GoogleResponseArray['routes'][0]['legs'][$x]['end_address'];
     $end_address = explode(",",$end_address)[0];
     $end_address = explode(" ",$end_address)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

The only known solution relies on parsing the string :

`$end_address = $GoogleResponseArray['routes'][0]['legs'][$x]['end_address'];`
`$end_address = explode(",", $end_address)[0];`
`$end_address = explode(" ", $end_address)[0];`